# Attempting to update multiple rows throws 512 error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can any one can give some alternate solution for the code below? I am receiving an 512 error while attempting to update multiple records.

```
update ActiveParty
set rmname = (select  CONCAT(rmname,rmadr1)
                from ActiveParty
                 where RMADR1 like ('%C/O%') or RMADR1 like ('%Attention%') or 
                 RMADR1 LIKE '%!%%' escape '!')
where RMADR1 in (select  RMADR1
                    from ActiveParty
                        where RMADR1 like ('%C/O%') or RMADR1 like 
                   ('%Attention%') or RMADR1 LIKE '%!%%' escape '!');
```

Comment: This will fail if the subselect of the set part returns more than 1 row. Scimon's answer is a good fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it more simply as:

```
update ActiveParty
set rmname = CONCAT(rmname,rmadr1)
where RMADR1 like ('%C/O%') 
    or RMADR1 like ('%Attention%') 
    or RMADR1 LIKE '%!%%' escape '!'
```